# Django test - How to send a HTTP Post Multipart with JSON

Tags: python, django, http, testing, post

in my django tests, I want to send an HTTP Post Multipart which contains 2 parameters:

- a JSON string
- a file

```python
def test_upload_request(self):
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False).name
    with open(temp_file) as f:
        file_form = {
            "file": f
        }
        my_json = json.dumps({
            "list": {
                "name": "test name",
                "description": "test description"
            }
        })
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:upload'),
                                    my_json,
                                    content=file_form,
                                    content_type="application/json")
    os.remove(temp_file)


def upload(request):    
    print request.FILES['file']
    print json.loads(request.body)
```

My code doesn't work. Any help ?
If necessary, I can use an external python lib (I'm trying with **requests**)
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `application/json` content-type, you cannot upload file.

Try following:

view:

```
def upload(request):
    print request.FILES['file']
    print json.loads(request.POST['json'])
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

test:

```
def test_upload_request(self):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        my_json = json.dumps({
            "list": {
                "name": "test name",
                "description": "test description"
            }
        })
        form = {
            "file": f,
            "json": my_json,
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:upload'),
                                    data=form)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: What if the file has to sit inside list. Then its not working.